# How to get WPF ListBox to always be the height of 4 grid rows?

Tags: wpf, listbox, grid, height, rows

How can i get my listbox to be the standard height of my rows, even after i add several items to the listbox?  I don't want to set a Height on either.  I've tried setting some shared size groups, tried binding the height of each of the rows to a different row, etc with no solution in sight.  I want the height of the four rows the listbox takes up to be the same height as they are originally.  The listbox currently grows to fit all the items in it, therefore making the rows taller, which i don't want.  I want the listbox to just get scrollbars if it is higher than 4 "normal" row heights.  If i MUST set a maxHeight on the listbox, how can i tell it to be 4x the height of one of my other rows?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="SharedSizes.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Border Margin="10" >
    <StackPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="C"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="D"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="E"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="F"/>

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition  Name="Row1" Height="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Width"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!--Left Side Parts-->

            <Label Content="Vendor:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" />

            <Label Content="Billing Model:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="125"/>

            <Label Content="Billing Cycle:" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Button Content="1"/>
                <Button Content="2"/>
                <Button Content="3"/>
                <Button  Content="4"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Clients" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!--<RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=Row1, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=Row1, Path=ActualHeight}" />
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=Row1, Path=ActualHeight}" />
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=Row1, Path=ActualHeight}" />-->
                <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Width"/>
                <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Width"/>
                <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Width"/>
                <RowDefinition  SharedSizeGroup="Width"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="C"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="D"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  />
                <ColumnDefinition  />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Content="Fred" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Label Content="Fred" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Label Content="Fred" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <Label Content="Fred" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
            <Label Content="Fred" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4"/>
            <Label Content="Fred" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Label Content="Fred" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <Label Content="Fred" Grid.Row="3"/>
            <ListBox Name="FredBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Grid.RowSpan="4"  Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

How I want it to look always (and how it does with no items in the listbox):

[image]

What it does after i added items to the listbox:

[image]

EDITED FOR VIV's SUGGESTIONS:

```
<Window x:Class="SharedSizes.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <!--<Style TargetType="{x:Type RowDefinition}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
    </Style>-->
</Window.Resources>

<Border Margin="10" >
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition  />
                <ColumnDefinition  />
                <ColumnDefinition  />
                <ColumnDefinition  />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!--Left Side Parts-->

            <Label Content="Vendor:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />

            <Label Content="Billing Model:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

            <Label Content="Billing Cycle:" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Button Content="1"/>
                <Button Content="2"/>
                <Button Content="3"/>
                <Button  Content="4"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=SomeLabel, Path=DesiredSize.Height}"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=SomeLabel, Path=DeisredSize.Height}"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=SomeLabel, Path=DeisredSize.Height}"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=SomeLabel, Path=DeisredSize.Height}"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition  />
                <ColumnDefinition  />
                <ColumnDefinition  />
                <ColumnDefinition  />
                <ColumnDefinition  />
                <ColumnDefinition  />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Content="Fred" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="SomeLabel"/>
            <Label Content="Fred" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Label Content="Fred" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
            <Label Content="Fred" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
            <Label Content="Fred" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4"/>
            <Label Content="Fred" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Label Content="Fred" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <Label Content="Fred" Grid.Row="3"/>
            <ListView Name="FredBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Grid.RowSpan="4"  />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

[image: Using Viv's suggestions]

Comment: If it tracks back to a size of Auto it is going to grow to fit the contents.

Comment: I think you either need to set the height of the list box, or set the height of the grid row.  Any reason you are opposed to this?  That fact that your outer-most container is a stackpanel is probably problematic as well as they usually have pretty unideal sizing of things.

Comment: If i must set it to a height, how can i tell it 4x the other rows?  I want all of my rows to basically be the same height. I guess i have to pick a height for the rows and apply it to all?

Comment: @user1029770 Yeah I'd just set up some buffer space on the bottom you want, and set up a row that contains nothing that the other things cannot grow into.

Comment: You should write your own VirtualizingStackPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do this by setting the `Grid.Row`'s `Height` using the `DesiredSize.Height` of the other item(the `Label`'s you have) in each row.

so by switching:

```
...
<!--<RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=Row1, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=Row1, Path=ActualHeight}" />
    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=Row1, Path=ActualHeight}" />
    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=Row1, Path=ActualHeight}" />-->
...
<Label Grid.Row="0"
       Content="Fred" />
...
```

to

```
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=SomeLabel, Path=DesiredSize.Height}" />
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=SomeLabel, Path=DesiredSize.Height}" />
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=SomeLabel, Path=DesiredSize.Height}" />
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=SomeLabel, Path=DesiredSize.Height}" />
...
<Label x:Name="SomeLabel"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Content="Fred" />
...
```

I'm just binding all 4 of the `RowDefinition.Height` to the same `Label` since all row's have the same item content and style anyways, but you get the picture hopefully. If they are different items in each row, give them a corresponding name and Bind each `RowDefinition` to the corresponding control.

This produces:

[image]

**Update:**

You've got a typo when you've tried my suggestion,

```
...
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=SomeLabel, Path=DesiredSize.Height}" />
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=SomeLabel, Path=DeisredSize.Height}"/>
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=SomeLabel, Path=DeisredSize.Height}"/>
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=SomeLabel, Path=DeisredSize.Height}"/>
...
```

Only row one is correct.

It's **`DesiredSize`** not **`DeisredSize`**

Comment: @Viv- I edited the original post to show results after I tried your suggestion.  I still see the listbox growing and the rows therefore becoming height too big also.  What is different from your solution?

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you for your help, this is doing exactly what i want now.  It's the little things, right?!